# Greyed out parameter with default value

Tags: reporting-services, parameters

There is a SSRS report with some parameters.

[image]

I have two problems. The most important is that one of the parameters ("`Código Titular`") is greyed although it has a default value and I would like it to be clear that there is a default value. The default value will only appear after the others that come first are set

All parameters are set to not refresh:

[image]

Is there a way to make the default value appear at the beginning? And also to prevent the parameter setting to refresh the page?

Comment: set them to automatically refresh (this is the default) . I seem to remember that you may also need to order the parameters so that the ones with default values are first. You need to do this by directly editing the order in the rdl. The order in the parameters pane is not important.

Comment: @AlanSchofield: Moving the ```Código Titular``` to first solves it. But the order of the other parameters with defaults (```UOP```, ```Moeda``` and ```Valorização```) does not matter. The difference from them is that ```Código Titular``` is a free text while the others come from queries without parameters and from a list. The refresh setting also does not make a difference.